# How to batch install multiple known addons?

Tags: add-on

I have several add-ons and I would like to bundle them together so that the user can just download all of them, but it would be nice if they could install all of them at one time.

Is there a way, either through Blender/Python or even a .bat file to do this easily?

Some of the addons are .zip and some are .py.

Comment: Does this help what you're after? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cD_4nKM1Wc

Comment: @blenderbreath thanks for the comment. I actually know about that and even reached out to the dev, but it's not in development or being supported any longer, I believe.